# Broken USB in Windows 10 1607

Tags: usb, windows-10-v1607

Since upgrading to 1607, i have lost the ability to access a few of my USB drives, most spessifically and urgently, my Garmin Forerunner 15 GPS watch.

The motherboard is an ASUS Sabertooth 990fx with the AMD 990FX/SB950 chipset.

I have tried the watched plugged in to USB2 and USB3 ports.

I have the latest drivers from both windows update and AMDs catalyst updater.

When i plug the watch in, i get the drive letter, but when i attempt to access it, i get "Please insert a disk into (G:)". Though if i right click and go to properties on the drive, and then go to "Hardware", i can see that it has my watch listed by name, along with its correct capacity (1mb).

Everything worked fine prior to 1607, and everything STILL works fine on the dual boot of Ubuntu that i can switch in to.

Are there any known issues/known fixes for USB devices suffering with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how i managed to just stumble on this KB, as i have been looking for days without any luck, but yes, this is a particular problem with Garmin watches.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3183365?sd=rss&spid=18165

The fix is to update to the latest version of Garmin Express

Comment: The KB seems to say that any mass storage formatted for FAT12, FAT16, and even FAT32 will no longer work under "Windows 10 Anniversary Update". Am I reading this right? Nice update then...